# Android sample HelloCompute not building correctly using target=android-21

Tags: android, eclipse, renderscript

I'm trying to build the "HelloCompute" android renderscript example in eclipse, with:

target=android-21

set in the project.properties file.

Eclipse does not generate the java files in the gen/ folder as it should so I can not run the example. Anyone knows why this does not work with target=android-21 but works just fine with  target=android-19?

Comment: Did you download Android 21 SDK via SDK Manager?

Comment: I have no idea if this is matters or not but did you change the buildToolsVersion ?

Comment: Zoltan: I just tested setting
sdk.buildtools=21.1.1
problem remains, builds ok with target=android-19 but fails with target=android-21.

Comment: Can you provide your failure messages log? Also, you need to make sure the SDK Platform 21, Android Support Repository and Android Support Library installed from the SDK manager.

Comment: There is no failure log, just an absence of the gen folder content that is generated if i used sdk 18 for example.